# Python subprocess restart not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

ive been looking at this for quite a while now and havent found anything that solves my problem so ill just try asking here. Thank you in advance.

Essentially, i have this script called gui.py which does something and at some point a Restart button appears. When that button is pressed the current process should be killed and gui.py should be called once again to restart the entire thing.

My current take was it for the button to print out "restart" and for the parent to read the stdout but that doesnt seem to work properly. I have also tried os.kill, sys.exit, exit(0), but once i call this in the subprocess the parent process dies withit which i guess is because the pid belongs to the parent effectively killing everything.

Here is my current code:

```
import subprocess
import time
import signal

def start_subprocess():
    return subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/python3.9', 'gui.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

def kill_subprocess(process):
    process.terminate()
    process.wait()

def main():
    process = start_subprocess()

    # subprocess init
    time.sleep(1)

    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline().decode().strip()

        if output == "restart":
            kill_subprocess(process)

            process = start_subprocess()

        if process.poll() is not None:
            break

        time.sleep(0.1)

    kill_subprocess(process)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```